# How to read a string with leading white spaces in C programming?

Tags: c

I tried reading a string with leading white spaces in C. I used `"%[^\n]%*c"` too but couldn't get leading white spaces.

**input:**
"   Language"
**output:**
"   Language"

Can anyone tell me how to read a string with leading white spaces in C? 
 [I am getting like this. But I want output same as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDLV.png)

Comment: There are [functions to read whole lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) without consideration of spaces.

Comment: While it's somewhat of a nuisance to use, and there are other, perhaps better ways, `%[^\n]%*c` should have worked.  Can you show us your exact code, and your exact input and output?

Comment: I just added the output I got. I want output same as input. My input is some string with white spaces in front of it

Comment: Your edits aren't making the question  more clear. You need to include a [mcve] showing what you have tried. Don't post images; copy-paste the code into your question post to make it easy for others to work with your code and answer your questions. You may want to read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `fgets()` function.The C library function `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either `(n-1)` characters are read, the `newline character` is read, or the `end-of-file` is reached, whichever comes first.

For example :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char String[100];
    fgets(String,100,stdin);
    printf("Output \n");
    puts(String);
}
```

**Output :-**

```
  Language
Output 
  Language
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks:)

Comment: Since the strategy suggested by OP (using `"%[^\n]%*c"`) should work, and OP hasn't provided any _actual_ code, we don't know what OP is doing wrong in the first place. This may be more valuable than just showing an alternative method.

Comment: The output is faked: `Language` should be on the next line, followed by 2 newlines.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Not to mention the undefined behavior when redirecting input from an empty file...

Comment: @chqrlie I have corrected the output. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read lines with significant spaces, definitely use `fgets()` instead of `scanf`.

Note in particular that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buf)` fails on empty lines and may cause undefined behavior on invalid input, just like `gets()`.